# Mail being delivered to both old and new server

Tags: email, hosting, share, nameserver

Two days ago I migrated our old site to a new server.  I turned down the ttl before I did it and some email is still going to our old server and some to our new after a little over 48 hours.  Both these are on shared hostgator sites.  From what I can tell everything is set up properly.  An nslookup points to the right ip address.  Any insight?  Support just tells me that everything is set up properly and I have to wait for propagation. I've never had it take over 48 hours though.

Comment: perhaps you're cached on the sender's end and they're just not looking up the MX record again. what was your old TTL?

Comment: 14400.  There are 2-3 clients who's email almost always goes to the old server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your setup is but if you are (or were) part of a large mail system make sure one of the MTAs isn't configured to still consider the old domain to be local.

We recently migrated out of a very large (county wide) mail system to Google Apps and while the MX records changed the MTA in the old system still considered our domain to be local so didn't look at the MX records before attempting delivery for mail that originated within that domain.

Comment: Great thought! I didn't even think of that, but it's bit me in the butt before.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the MX records for the 2-3 clients whose emails are going to the wrong server are correct? Have you tried running a [DNS Report](http://dnsreport.com) on the problematic domains? What do the email headers for the mis-delivered emails say, are there any clues in there?  Are you sure you updated the serial number for the zone files?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is just because some providers don't pay any attention to DNS TTLs. Add a transport map or a relay on the old server to forward all mail to the new one, rather than deliver it locally.